# how to make accessible, responsive, flexible masked images with alt tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I built a website layout that currently relies on flexible divs with images stored in the background because their flexibility helps make the content responsive for all window sizes; however, I also want to add alt tags so the meaningful content is accessible and also SEO-friendly. It seems I have a semantic challenge.

There are spacer images keeping those flexible containers open, so I could put alt tags on those, but I understand that would be frowned upon by search engines. I'm not trying to stuff the site with fake keywords. At the same time, I don't want to leave important keywords out.

In summary, I want the images to be both accessible and responsive. Is there a cross-browser solution that is backwards-compatible with older browsers? I'm not finding a lot of current information on this topic. I was looking at some form of image masking, but again I'm not seeing agreement on this topic. What works for you?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Here's the work in progress: https://www.greatgraphicdesign.com/work/bsp/index.html

Comment: First thing is it compulsory to use image as a background? if yes then i prefer to you to change `background-size` `cover` to `contain` so you user see full image of your product but unfortunately it didn't allow alt tag for you image and as its product site so `alt` tag is compulsory for SEO!!!!!!Second its good to use `<img>` tag which support `alt` tag so that you easily name you images and for make it responsive you need to use `object-fit` property along with `image` height and `width` so that you image didn't cropped as this images make this site important

Comment: object-fit saves the day!! Thank you! I will update my site.

Comment: Good to hear that @chilly :)